# Clearing the value of a Multi-Select Picklist using API

Tags: salesforce

I have a very simple question - How do I use the PHP Soap API to clear the value of a Multi-Select picklist in Salesforce? I can update other fields to my heart's content, but if I try and update that field with an empty string, it does nothing.

I know I'm missing something simple about this, can someone point me int he right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to add the picklist field name to the sObject [fieldsToNull](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421117) string array.

This will clear the value.

Comment: So I would do something like this?

`$lead = new stdclass();
$lead->Id = $record->Id;
$lead->fieldsToNull = array('Custom_Field_1__c', 'Custom_Field_2__c');`

And then run it through the Update command?

Comment: @Lisa, I'm not familiar with PHP, but that seems about right.